# Array offset error in Laravel 4

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4

I have following array

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#96 (1) {
      ["items":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(Answer)#97 (20) {
          ["connection":protected]=>
          NULL
          ["table":protected]=>
          NULL
          ["primaryKey":protected]=>
          string(2) "id"
          ["perPage":protected]=>
          int(15)
          ["incrementing"]=>
          bool(true)
          ["timestamps"]=>
          bool(true)
          ["attributes":protected]=>
          array(6) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(457256)
            ["question_id"]=>
            int(3124)
            ["user_id"]=>
            int(1235)
            ["answer_text"]=>
            string(44) "Sincere Architects Engineers Private Limited"
            ["created_at"]=>
            string(19) "2015-08-10 06:18:06"
            ["updated_at"]=>
            string(19) "2015-08-10 06:39:33"
          }
          ["original":protected]=>
          array(6) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(457256)
            ["question_id"]=>
            int(3124)
            ["user_id"]=>
            int(1235)
            ["answer_text"]=>
            string(44) "Sincere Architects Engineers Private Limited"
            ["created_at"]=>
            string(19) "2015-08-10 06:18:06"
            ["updated_at"]=>
            string(19) "2015-08-10 06:39:33"
          }
          ["relations":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["hidden":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["visible":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["appends":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["fillable":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["guarded":protected]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(1) "*"
          }
          ["dates":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["touches":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["observables":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["with":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["morphClass":protected]=>
          NULL
          ["exists"]=>
          bool(true)
        }
        [1]=>
        object(Answer)#98 (20) {
          ["connection":protected]=>
          NULL
          ["table":protected]=>
          NULL
          ["primaryKey":protected]=>
          string(2) "id"
          ["perPage":protected]=>
          int(15)
          ["incrementing"]=>
          bool(true)
          ["timestamps"]=>
          bool(true)
          ["attributes":protected]=>
          array(6) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(457257)
            ["question_id"]=>
            int(3125)
            ["user_id"]=>
            int(1235)
            ["answer_text"]=>
            string(14) "Anoop Bartaria"
            ["created_at"]=>
            string(19) "2015-08-10 06:18:06"
            ["updated_at"]=>
            string(19) "2015-08-10 06:39:33"
          }
          ["original":protected]=>
          array(6) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(457257)
            ["question_id"]=>
            int(3125)
            ["user_id"]=>
            int(1235)
            ["answer_text"]=>
            string(14) "Anoop Bartaria"
            ["created_at"]=>
            string(19) "2015-08-10 06:18:06"
            ["updated_at"]=>
            string(19) "2015-08-10 06:39:33"
          }
          ["relations":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["hidden":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["visible":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["appends":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["fillable":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["guarded":protected]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(1) "*"
          }
          ["dates":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["touches":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["observables":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["with":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["morphClass":protected]=>
          NULL
          ["exists"]=>
          bool(true)
        }
      }
    }
```

It clearly shows that It has two values that is `[0] and [1]` but when I 
`var_dump(array[0])`

it says `offset error :0`

any leads on this one would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to var_dump(your-variable-name[0]); it should work

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dd($array->toArray());` to print as Array. Which convert collection in array. Same you can use `dd($array->toJson());` to print in Json format.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have an array, you have a Colleciton object, you can get items using all (http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_all) method and then you can dump the returned array.

Comment: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` extends `Illuminate\Support\Collection` which implements `ArrayAccess`. That means Collection objects can be used like arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following,

`var_dump(json_decode($array,true)[0]);`

`json_decode($array,true)` --> this statement will convert the collection object into an array. Once this is done, you can access the array using the array index

Thank you :)